# MS Access Database Task Costing

Tags: ms-access

I have a Theory question, I have an access database and I want to track cost by task. Currently I have a task tracker table that will store the users Hours|HourlyRate and Overtime|OvertimeRate among other things work order no, project no etc. I don't think that this is the best way to store this data as the users could look at the table and see each others rates, before now it didn't matter much, but I'm about to give this database to more users. I was thinking of having that Rate data in a separate table linked to the ID no of the Task table and not allow users to have access to this table, but then I couldn't do an after update event as the user wont have access to write to that table. Either that or store the rates in a separate Database with a start and end date of that given rate. For instance:

```
Ed | Rate $0.01 | StartDate 01/01/1999 | EndDate 12/32/1999
Ed | Rate $0.02 | StartDate 01/01/2000 | EndDate 12/32/2000
```

This way I can store the costing data in a separate database that the users don't have access too and just calculate the cost information every time I need it based on date and unique user ID. I was wondering what solutions have others come up within MSAccess for this type of situation.

Comment: Users should not interact with any tables or queries. Manage what users see via forms and reports. But if you want to split backend that it is certainly an option.

Comment: The database is split, with linked tables. I have the form that users enter data, but from my understanding even if I make a .accde file and turn off the navigation bar. the user can turn on the navigation bar and open the table directly. This is what I am trying to prevent.

Comment: Try an accdr extension. Change by simply changing b to r in the file extension. Yes, db is split with FE/BE but an addition you want to split the BE into 2 files.